# jQuery Mobile does not process elements in Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I'm converting my site from using jQueryUI to jQuery Mobile, and I'm having some trouble.

I have a page that lets users add new timesheet entries. They click the "Add" button and it retrieves a Partial View from the server right onto the page.

The problem is that jQuery Mobile is not applying to any of the elements in the Partial View.

How can I force jQuery Mobile to process my elements after they've been inserted into the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can just trigger the `create` method on the parent element of where you inserting your partial view.

For example `$('#container').trigger( "create" );`

Alternatively most widgets can be manually initialized by calling them on the element, for example for a listview: `$('#myListview').listview()`. This can be useful if you have only a few elements that need to be enhaced and you don't want to traverse all the child elements of the container. You should also know that for many widgets there is also a refresh method which you can call if you add elements to it after it has already been initialized for example `$('#myListview').listview('refresh)`.

Also have a look at the following [Q & A](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/faq/injected-content-is-not-enhanced.html) from the JQM docs which deals with this issue and for an explanation as to why it is necessary to call these methods.

> Question: Content injected into a page is not enhanced.
>
> Answer:
>
> jQuery Mobile has no way to know when you have injected content into a
>   page. To let jQuery Mobile know you have injected content that must be
>   enhanced, you need to either make sure the plugins are called to
>   enhance the new elements or trigger("create") on the parent container
>   so you don't have to call each plugin manually.

Comment: Your welcome, it's worth glancing at some the other Q & A's listed for some of the common *catches* that you might encounter when using JQM.